# Does Hashtable get method returns more than one value?

Tags: java, get, hashtable

I was converting some code from java to C#, I encountered `ArrayList<Integer> values = hashtable.get(h);`. Question aroused **Does Hashtable get method returns more than one value?**

Comment: Think template when you encounter a Java generic

Comment: It returns an object. In your case you would get an object of ArrayList<Integer>. It's not more than one: it's a single instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `HashTable` returns one value. If that value happens to be an object of type `Collection`, then that one value will point to several other values.

**For example**

```
HashTable<String, ArrayList<Integer>> table = new HashTable<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();

// Populate it with values.

ArrayList<Integer> value = table.get("KEY");
```

**How is this possible?**

Simple. Java Generics. This is where you declare a `Generic type` in a class, and you define it's type at run time. For example:

```
public class Test<T>
{
      private T instance;

      public Test(T instance)
      {
          this.instance = instance;
      }
}
```

That means you can declare this class any way you want.

```
Test<String> test = new Test<String>();
Test<Integer> test2 = new Test<Integer>();
```

And the type of `instance` will be whatever you declare it as.

And because `T` defaults to type `Object`, you can even put a `Collection` in there.

```
Test<ArrayList<String>> test3 = new Test<ArrayList<String>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

An ArrayList is one value (an arraylist) by itself

```
HashTable<something, ArrayList<Integer>> hashtable = new HashTable<something, ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

So it's gonna map the "something" to an arraylist of integers (i.e. a list)

Answer (score 0):

The return type of [`get() method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) is `Object`. So it is a single `Object`. But the type  can be a `List` or Any `Class` in Java.

So the returning `Object` purely  depends on What you inserted before.

Answer (score 0):

If you wold like to have many values for one key use `Guava` => `Multimap`
Documentation:
http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Answer (score 0):

It does only return a list of values if you put that list in the map (under the certain key).

```
Map<String, List<Object>> map = new HashMap<>();
... // init map
List<Object> list = map.get(KEY);
```

but

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(KEY, obj1);
map.put(KEY, obj2);
Object obj = map.get(KEY);
```